# how to sync two tables from two different databases from two different servers- in PHP SQLI

Tags: php, sql, database, synchronization

I have a database on another server. I want to get the data from another server and post it on my server (without duplicate on ID number).

How to do this as auto sync or manually in PHP.

Structure is given below:

```
SERVER1          |    SERVER2
db1              |    db1
__________________________________
db1.emp          |    db1.emp
__________________________________
phone_no         |    phone_no
emp_email        |    emp_email
home_address     |    home_address
```

Comment: You can open two SQL connections using a method/function according to your DB (MySQL, MSSQL etc.). What to you mean by "click on PHP"? and SQLi means SQL Injection, do you need your code to be vulnerable?

Comment: When I click a button on my php page, these two different tables should sync (from two different servers)